# jquery.min.js GET request returns 404 error after Wordpress site migration

Tags: jquery, wordpress, caching, woocommerce, http-status-code-404

Recently we migrated Wordpress site with WooCommerce from VPS to a specialized WP hosting.
The migration was supposed to be 1-to-1 exact copy of files and database, php version is the same (7.4).

Issue: On the new website WooCommerce cart is stuck loading the products and cart content and throws

```
GET https://some-page-here 404 ..... jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
```

in Chrome Console.

in the details of this error in Console I see the following:

```
ajax    @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
s.ajax.s.ajax   @   jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=3.3.2:2
update_checkout_action  @   checkout.min.js?ver=4.6.5:1
setTimeout (async)      
update_checkout @   checkout.min.js?ver=4.6.5:1
dispatch    @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
v.handle    @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
trigger @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
(anonymous) @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
each    @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
each    @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
trigger @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
init_checkout   @   checkout.min.js?ver=4.6.5:1
dispatch    @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
v.handle    @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
trigger @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
(anonymous) @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
each    @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
each    @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
trigger @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
init    @   checkout.min.js?ver=4.6.5:1
(anonymous) @   checkout.min.js?ver=4.6.5:1
e   @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
t   @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
setTimeout (async)      
(anonymous) @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
c   @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
fireWith    @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
fire    @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
c   @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
fireWith    @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
ready   @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
B   @   jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
```

I do not know how to read the sequence above and wether it gives me some idea on what is the nature of the issue.

What I have tried:

1. Located the jquery.min.js in wp-includes/js/jquery.min.js, the file is there.
2. purged all the possible cache (CDN by Cloudflare, local minified cache, browser cache) as I was said by the hosting support, that the issue is somehow related to cache, that causes errors after migration. Also the suffix of `?ver=3.6.0:2`  in the file name gives us the idea, that the file is cached by some agent.
3. Tried switching off plugins related to caching or security, but no luck.

Please advise, if there is a known solution for that?
Hosting support (who actually performed migration and who also are WP specialised support) did not help yet.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this issue was related to a conflict with WP Plugin called "LearnDash Courses tab as BB Homepage". Switching off the plugin solved the issue.